# Reload GameScene without reloading UIScene in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have 2 scenes "GamePlay" and "GameUI".

I load GameUI additively with GamePlay

```
void Awake () {
    if (!instance) {
        instance = this;
    } else {
        Destroy(this.gameObject) ;
    }

    SceneManager.LoadScene ("GameUI", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
}
```

Now when I reload the "GamePlay" scene using

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

How can I prevent reloading "GameUI" scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `MonoBehaviour` that is attached to the GameUI which contains a static bool that indicates if the object exists. Make your whole UI Scene a child of one object with the following script.

```
public class UIExistance : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool Exists { get; private set; }

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);
        UIExistance.Exists = true;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        UIExistance.Exists = false;
    }
}
```

When you are in your posted `Awake` method you can check with `if(!UIExistance.Exists)` whether the UI is already in the scene.